# why is the time complexity of bubble sort's best case being O(n)

Tags: time-complexity, bubble-sort

I deduced the time complexity of bubble sort in its best case according to the mothod used in book **ALGORITHMS** 2.2. But the answer turned out to be O(n^2).

Here's my derivation, hope anyone can help me find out where is wrong:

```
public void bubbleSort(int arr[]) {
for(int i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
        if(arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
            swap(arr, j, j + 1);
    }
}
```

}

```
Statements                      cost    times
i = 0,len = arr.length          c1          1
i < len - 1                     c2          n
i++                             c3          n - 1
j = 0                           c4          n - 1
j < len - i - 1                 c5          t1(i=0) + t1(i=1) + ... + t1(i = n-2)
j++                             c6          t2(i=0) + t2(i=1) + ... + t2(i = n-2)
arr[j + 1] < arr[j]             c7          t3(i=0) + t3(i=1) + ... + t3(i = n-2)
swap(arr, j, j + 1)             c8          t4(i=0) + t4(i=1) + ... + t4(i = n-2)
```

T(n) = c1 + c2n + c3(n - 1) + c4(n - 1) + c5t5 + c6t6 + c7t7 + c8t8
     = c1 + c2n + c3(n - 1) + c4(n - 1) + c5[t1(i=0) + t1(i=1) + ... + t1(i = n-2)] + c6[t2(i=0) + t2(i=1) + ... + t2(i = n-2)] + c7[t3(i=0) + t3(i=1) + ... + t3(i = n-2)] + c8[t4(i=0) + t4(i=1) + ... + t4(i = n-2)];

in its best cast, the sequence is already positive before sorting. Then t8 sould be 0.

T(n) = c1 + c2n + c3(n - 1) + c4(n - 1) + c5[t1(i=0) + t1(i=1) + ... + t1(i = n-2)] + c6[t2(i=0) + t2(i=1) + ... + t2(i = n-2)] + c7[t3(i=0) + t3(i=1) + ... + t3(i = n-2)]

The time complexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your implementation

```
public void bubbleSort(int arr[]) {
    for(int i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
            if(arr[j + 1] < arr[j])
                swap(arr, j, j + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

lacks the control whether there was any swap in the inner loop, and the breaking out of the outer loop if there wasn't.

That control makes it possible that the best case (an already sorted array) is O(n), since then there are no swaps in the inner loop when it runs the first time.

```
public void bubbleSort(int arr[]) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    for(int i = 0, len = arr.length; swapped && i < len - 1; i++) {
        swapped = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
            if(arr[j + 1] < arr[j]) {
                swap(arr, j, j + 1);
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When analyzing algorithms, though, it's best not to assume anything except the bare-bones implementation. In this case, we have to assume bubble sort will not be implemented as an optimized version that breaks looping if it never swaps any values.

Comment: @AleksandrH True. But for Bubble sort, at least some authors (e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)) include the check in the definition.

Answer (score 2):

The best case for bubble sort is when the elements are already sorted.

The usual implementation gives O(n^2) time complexity for best, average, worst case.

We can modify the bubble sort by checking  if array is sorted or not(a swap would indicate an unsorted array) at every iteration.

As soon as the array is found to be sorted(if no swap occurs) control exits from loops or loop continues to execute till length-1.

And same is true for insertion sort as well!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you counting. In general, when you are talking about *comparison sort algorithms* you should count the number of comparisons made. Bubble sort is regarded as such. In this case the algorithm you presented is O(n^2).

If you count the number of swaps its O(1) or maybe even one could say O(0). It is however rare to analyze Bubble sort like that.

You can, however very easily improve Bubble to get O(N) on best case. E.g by introducing a flag `swap_was_made`. If its false at the end of inner `for` you can finish. On best case it will cut complexity to O(N)  (one inner for loop). In case of fair even distribution it cuts the expected or average complexity to O(N^2/2) ... But please double check me on it I might be wrong. Didn't do the math here.

Comment: Just to be clear, the average case (randomly ordered) number of swaps is still something like O(N^2).  It's only the best-case number of swaps that's 0.  (Which is in the complexity class O(1).)

Comment: Re: the benefit of an early-out check:  O( 0.5 * N^2 ) is the same complexity class as O( N^2 ).  And even one "[turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Rabbits_and_turtles)" that has a long way to move will prevent early-out.  Unlike Insertion Sort that only needs one pass to fix one mis-placed element, whether it's a low element near the end or a high element near the start.  If you're counting exact numbers of compares or swaps, rather than looking at complexity classes, later outer iterations are cheaper since the inner loop range gets shorter if implemented optimally.