# What is the time complexity of this loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

How can one determine the time complexity of this loop:

```
for(int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
        if(numbers[j-1] > numbers[j])
        {
            temp = numbers[j-1];
            numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

As you may have noticed this is the algorithm for bubble sort. Also is the frequency count of this algorithm for comparison and assignment the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "frequency count"?

Comment: Do you mean the time complexity, the 'big O' time?

Comment: Yes I mean time complexity, I don't know what it is called specifically but I want to find the more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calculate the complexity

You need to add the **basic operations**/**machine instructions** that are being executed. (as a function of the size of it's input)

### Calculation

```
for(int i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
{          |        |     |
           c1       c2    c3
   for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
   {       |        |     |
           c4       c5    c6
      if(numbers[j-1] > numbers[j])--c7
      {
         temp = numbers[j-1];
         numbers[j-1] = numbers[j];
         numbers[j] = temp;
      }
   }
}
```

c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7 are the costs to execute the machine instructions corresponding to these constructs (like i>=0,j<=i etc)

```
Now for i=N-1 the innerloop is executed N-1 times
    for i=N-2 the innerloop is executed N-2 times
    ....

    for i=0 the innerloop is executed 0 times
```

So the innerloop is executed `(N-1)+(N-2)+...1+0` times which is
                           =  N*(N-1)/2

```
Look carefully the cost is
 = c1+ c2*(N+1) + c3*N+ c4*N+((N*(N-1)/2)+1)*(c5)+ (N(N-1)/2)*(c6+c7);
 = c1+c2+c5+ N*(c2+c3-(c5+c6+c7)/2) + N^2 * (c5/2 + c6/2 + c7/2)
 = c8 + N*c9 + N^2 *(c10)   [c8,c9,c10 are constants]
```

Why do we multiply N+1 with c2 ? that is because of the last check when actually `i=-1`.

Now for large values of N, N^2 dominates N.
So the time complexity is O(N^2).
    So, **T(N)=O(N^2)**

Comment: why is the cost of c4 == c4*N and not c4*(N*(N-1)/2)? Isn't c4 executed as many times as the inner loop?

Comment: @Justin.: That's how the for loop works - we initialize it once for the loop index variable - not for every iteration that loop does. That's why `c4*N`.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of your current implementation is O(n^2) for both best and worst cases, and is the same if count only comparisons, only assignments, or both.

Here are the detailed calculations, K being a constant depending on which operations you want to take into account for time complexity:

[image]

If you want a more efficient Bubble sort algorithm, check out the pseudo codes on the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505888/3854322), you will find algorithms with O(n) best case complexity.